# spring 4.1.1, mockmvc and do not want url encoding of HTTP GET request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

Using MockMVC in tests and I need to test a GET URL that is already URL encoded:

```
http://host:port/app/controller/[ALREADY URL ENCODED]
```

The code:

```
mockmvc.perform(get("/controller/[ALREADY URL ENCODED]")
```

However in the logs  I see that the URL has been url encoded again before it gets to the appropriate controller method. Is there a way that we can prevent spring mockmvc to url encode? Perhaps disable url encoding in the test?

Real example of the "[ALREADY URL ENCODED]" string:

```
MEUwQzBBMD8wPTAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBQ%2Fm36Fj2BE19VBYXRO62zrgIYp0gQVAQazEyvlq22wsMBkRyAeaUiZ%2BhTUAgMGJbQ%3D
```

This gets URL encoded again before the controller sees it.

This is from the logs (the string has been url encoded again)

```
xxxxx [main] DEBUG [o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet]  DispatcherServlet with name '' processing GET request for [/app/controller/MEUwQzBBMD8wPTAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBQ%252Fm36Fj2BE19VBYXRO62zrgIYp0gQVAQazEyvlq22wsMBkRyAeaUiZ%252BhTUAgMGJbQ%253D]
```

Note that if I invoke using CURL then there is no url encoding performed by the spring framework and the controller gets what is sent across. However mockmvc would do the encoding before it gets to the appropriate controller method.

```
curl -X GET http:host:port/app/controller/[ALREADY URL ENCODED]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please give a real example. Spring will only url encode necessary characters.

Comment: Edited with the real example of an already url encoded string

Comment: Now please post what you receive on the controller side. How can you tell it was re-encoded? Which characters are encoded the second time?

Comment: The "%" is one example of a character getting encoded again.

Comment: Please show us because I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix it? I am facing the same problem as you...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What works for me is `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(new URI([ENCODED_URL_STRING]))`.

I guess there is alternative using `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(String urlTemplate, Object... urlVariables)`, with appropriate urlVariables, but I haven't gone deeper.

Comment: This works and was added with Spring 4.0.3, see the bug report: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11441

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I created my own URI matcher to use with MockMvc:

```
public class RequestToUriMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    private final String expectedUri;

    public RequestToUriMatcher(String expectedUri){
        this.expectedUri = expectedUri;
    }

    @Override
    public void match(ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest) throws IOException, AssertionError {
        URI requestUri = clientHttpRequest.getURI();
        //requestUri is encoded, so if request was made with query parameter already encoded, this would be double-encoded, so decoding it once here
        String decodedUri = URLDecoder.decode(requestUri.toString(), "UTF-8");
        assertTrue(decodedUri.endsWith(expectedUri));
    }
}
```

Followed by a static method:

```
public static RequestMatcher requestToUri(String uri){
    return new RequestToUriMatcher(uri);
}
```

Now I can use it like so:

```
String uri = "stuff%3Dvalue";
MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate)
    .expect(requestToUri(uri))/**/
```

It is not a perfect solution, but for the sake of lack of other solutions, it works...

Comment: Your answer is for the MockRestServiceServer, but the question is about MockMvc