# SpringBoot mockmvc truncates part of the path variable's value at the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application with the following Restful method

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getVersion/{version}", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity getSpecific(@PathVariable("version") String version) throws Exception{
    // return ResponseEntity();
}
```

And here is the corresponding junit method.

```
@Test
public void testGetSpecific() throws Exception{
     // Version - timestamp in Zulu format
     String path = "/getVersion/" + DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now());
     MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(url + path).secure(false).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
}
```

Problem:
The value of version sent during testing is not same at the controller end.

Eg: If we send **2019-05-21T20:18:08.157Z** in test method, we would receive **2019-05-21T20:18:08** at controller. And thus, we would miss the part **.157Z**.

I tried the solutions described in the following links, but no luck.

[spring 4.1.1, mockmvc and do not want url encoding of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722589/spring-4-1-1-mockmvc-and-do-not-want-url-encoding-of-http-get-request)

[RestTemplate to NOT escape url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182836/resttemplate-to-not-escape-url)

Could anyone point to whats happening behind the scenes and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot (I'd seriously consider passing the instant as a numerical value, though)

Comment: works fine for me @ test `/getVersion/2019-05-24T20:07:47.538879Z` and at controller `2019-05-24T20:07:47.538879Z`, using spring-boot 2.1.1

Comment: The deleted answer is correct. ISO_INSTANT doesn't have a decimal component. It formats like '2011-12-03T10:15:30Z'.

Comment: @crizzis Thanks. The link was helpful.